# Drupal 7: Protect entire site in a maintaince mode-esque fashion

Tags: 7, maintenance-mode

Looking for a way to lock down the site like maintenance mode, but without having to use maintenance mode.

I don't want to use maintenance mode because I want to have that feature available for it's proper use.

However, I would like to able to have the site viewable as normal for logged in users, and anonymous users just get a screen telling them to login or register. Probably with a login/register box as well.  So hopefully something with a template.

Any modules out there or maybe a simple custom module?

Comment: Why isn't maintenance mode appropriate for you? You can customize the template to say what you want, and control what roles have access to view the site in the mode.

Comment: @Brian Because what if I actually need to use maintenance mode to lock out ALL users.  Well, it's already in use.  Plus I don't want the message to appear in the DSM area. Which I know can be changed but, there is obviously a right way to do this, and a lazy way. I'm looking for the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the permission that allows users to view published content.  They'll get an access denied message.  Create a custom 403 page with the login info and poof!  Robert's your mother's brother.

Comment: Thanks Robert my Mother's Brother.  That solution could do the trick.  Cheers.

Comment: Tee hee:  "Robert's your mother's brother" equals "Bob's your uncle".  Silly colloquialisms.

Answer (score 0):

print screen a login and register page of drupal and enabled it in front page so that the user could see the login and register button.